# Difference between "<T extends Comparable<T>>" and "<T extends Comparable<Comparable<T>>>"?

Tags: java, generics, interface

In the expression `<T extends Comparable<T>>` in a signature like

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> foo(T x) { ... }
```

the description of `T` depends recursively on `Comparable<T>`.

If `T` extends `Comparable<T>`, and `Comparable<T>` extends `Comparable<Comparable<T>>`, doesn't it follow that `T` extends `Comparable<Comparable<T>>`?

IOW, is the `extends` relationship transitive?

If so, why isn't

```
public static <T extends Comparable<Comparable<T>>> int compare(T x, T y) {
    return x.compareTo(y);
}
```

equivalent to

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int compare(T x, T y) {
    return x.compareTo(y);
}
```

?  In fact, the last definition compiles, whereas the one above it fails to compile, with the error

```
comp.java:7: compareTo(java.lang.Comparable<T>) in 
java.lang.Comparable<java.lang.Comparable<T>> cannot be applied to (T)
            return x.compareTo(y);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have a syntax error `Comparable<T>>`  should be `Comparable<T> > `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental issue to keep in mind is that Java generics are scoped by the compilation unit and compile time.  *It is just syntactic sugar!* (How many times I forget this and end up reasoning precisely the way you do, *as if* Java Generics actually implied *a generic type system in runtime*.)

From [the spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.2):

```
The scope of a class' type parameter is the entire declaration of the class 
including the type parameter section itself. 

Therefore, type parameters can appear as parts of their own bounds, or as 
bounds of other type parameters declared in the same section.
```

There is no recursion, and no new types are defined.

To wit:

```
package so_6949760;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class SweetCompilingGenerics {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class Sweet<X> extends HashMap<X, Sweet<X>> {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sweet<String> sweetStr = new Sweet<String>();
        Sweet<Sweet<Integer>> whatever = new Sweet<SweetCompilingGenerics.Sweet<Integer>>();

        assert sweetStr.getClass().equals(whatever.getClass()) : "who made generics a runtime mechanism?";
        assert sweetStr.getClass() == whatever.getClass() : "who made generics a runtime mechanism?";

        System.out.format("Is %s a Sweet<String> ?\n", sweetStr.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        System.out.format("Is %s a Sweet<Sweet<Integer>> ?\n", whatever.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

Will output the sweet secret:

```
Is so_6949760.SweetCompilingGenerics.Sweet a Sweet<String> ? 
Is so_6949760.SweetCompilingGenerics.Sweet a Sweet<Sweet<Integer>> ?
```

May I be so forward to offer an advice to a fellow geek?  *Always read the specification*.

[post accept edit]:  Just found this [highly informative article by IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255/index.html). That pretty much addresses all of OP's questions. (Recommended).

Comment: thanks for the very instructive response; your advice about the spec is on target, and it's typically what I do, but in this case, I don't understand what the specs (i.e. what you quoted) are saying; unannotated specs can be close to useless sometimes.  I get the part about the loss of the parameter info at runtime (so the `assert`s in your code hold, for example), but I still don't understand why the `extends` relationship is not transitive, while the `isAssignableFrom` relationship is, since I thought the former implied the latter...

Comment: Also, by "syntactic sugar" I understand a "convenient, but inessential, shorthand", that can always be replaced by a (probably more cumbersome) expression consisting entirely of "fundamental" syntactic components.  If this is more or less what you had in mind when you described generics as "syntactic sugar", what is it sugar for?  I.e. what is the corresponding de-sugared syntax?

Comment: @kjo: Readup on 'type erasure'.  `Foo afoo = (Foo) list.get(n);` will be the end result but of course the compiler and type system (@compile time) are involved so its not just text replacement. Certainly hear you about the spec, specially the relevant section. But note "discussion" sections are the meta-discussion (ala "annotation") and that does do a good job dispelling initial false thoughts e.g. that runtime comp code segment is very informative, isn't it?

Comment: @kjo: difficult to address transitive Q in comment. Really needs a diagram. Google is failing me as I can't find a page describing the reference implementation (as doc not code). That wil dive into type-erase, 'capture-of', and how the generic info is retained by (already compiled) classes, etc. Key: generics are scoped by compilation unit (so reasoning across units requires this step down to 'capture-of' (a matter of concern to the compiler) vs 'sub-type-of'. (At least that's as far as I have figured it out :)

Comment: @kjo: just added a link at bottom.

Answer (score 4):

You've made an incorrect logical jump here, I think.

```
T extends Comparable<T>
```

does **not** imply that

```
Comparable<T> extends Comparable<Comparable<T>>
```

---

**Short analogy**:

Suppose a *rock-crusher* is any material that can crush *rock*, and *rock* just happens to be capable of crushing itself. So rock is a rock-crusher. Does this mean that rock can crush any substance which can crush rock? Clearly not: *steel* might also be a rock-crusher while rock might not crush steel.

---

**Long (code-based) analogy**:

Suppose I have an interface, `Additive<T>`, which can be used to describe any type to which you may perform an `add` operation on a `T` object and get back a `T`.

Now let's say I have some method whose signature looks like this:

```
public static <T extends Additive<T>> add(T x, T y) { ... }
```

Since `x` must be of a type to which I can add a `T`, this method could be implemented as follows:

```
return x.add(y);
```

Make sense? OK, great; but now let's make the assumption you've made in your question: that `Additive<T>` must extend `Additive<Additive<T>>`; if this is the case then I can assume that I can add to `x` an instance of *any type implementing* `Additive<T>`.

Here's where the assumption breaks down. I might have a type, say...

```
// A 32-bit integral number supporting addition
public class Int32 implements Additive<Int32> { ... }
```

That would make sense, right? I could also have something like this:

```
// A list of 32-bit integral numbers supporting appending
public class Int32List implements Additive<Int32> { ... }
```

Now, if `T extends Additive<T>` implied that `Additive<T> extends Additive<Additive<T>>` then I should be able to do this:

```
Additive<Int32> x = new Int32(5);
Additive<Int32> y = x.add(new Int32List());
```

Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special about

```
<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

Consider

```
public class Foo implements Comparable<Foo>{
     int compareTo(Foo x);
}
```

I don't even think we can say that it's defined recursively, it's just self referential.

Answer (score 1):

> `Comparable<T> extends Comparable<Comparable<T>>`

Perhaps I misunderstand what relationship you are conveying, but this statement is untrue. `Comparable<T>` does not extend anything.

Answer (score 0):

`Comparable<T>` does not extend `Comparable<Comparable<T>>` (just because `T` extends `Comparable<T>`) in the same way that `List<String>` does not extend `List<Object>` (just because `String` extends `Object`).

Please refer to [this document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) from Oracle to read more about generics and inheritance.